# Login in wso2-is without tenant domain

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've got a service-provider declared in a tenant; is there a way to login a tenant user in wso2 without tenant domain in username? (not tenant admin user)

[what I want in this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NppWK.png)

Comment: What is the IS version you are on? Because 5.10.0 supports this out of the box.

Comment: I'm using 5.9 but I've to update to 5.10. What i ve to do? Is it automatically?

Comment: is there any documentation explaining how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supported out of the box in 5.10.0. But for earlier versions, you can do like below.

In the login page, you will receive the tenant domain as a query parameter. So you can append it to the end of the username on the onSubmit event of the login form with the help of javascript.

But this won't work for SaaS service providers because we are using the service provider's tenant as the user tenant.